# Problem creating Appium driver while using selenium 4,9,1 and Appium.Webdriver 4.4.5

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium-android, selenium4

We have a test framework where we use selenium webdriver with C#. We are using Selenium webdriver 4.9.1 and Appium.Webdriver 4.4.5.

When I try to create Appium webdriver as below it gives me the error

> Error CS7069  Reference to type 'IFindsById' claims it is defined in 'WebDriver', but it could not be found

How can I create appiumdriver -   [image: static AndroidDriver appiumDriver;]

How should I resolve this?
I do not understand the error exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appium web driver 4.4.0 is not compatible with selenium 4. One will need to update to appium dotnet client version 5.x beta release. THen it worked fine.

https://github.com/appium/dotnet-client/issues/600